# Owncloud Appliance SSH key fail to import

Tags: ssh

Steps refer to instructions on the page for installing the Owncloud appliance for Raspberry Pi 3 and 4.

ssh-keygen -t rsa runs fine (step 3)  keys are generated.

Step 4 makes no sense to me.  "~.ssh/id_rsa.pub" is not a command (yes,I didn't use the quotes) and I just get an error message saying so.  I can nano into the file and copy the key, but when I click "import" on the webpage to register the key, it says it isn't a valid ssh key.  It does have the correct prefix and a whole lot of numbers ending in >.   What am I missing?

Comment: hello, pls be more clear what instructions you followed (perhaps a link might help)

Comment: A link to the instructions would be very helpful. Looks like a typo: Should be `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Answer (score 0):

To make this work step 4 in the installation proceedure has to use the cat command to get the proper listing from the id_rsa.pub file.

Surprising what a god night's sleep can do.